# Publishing a new set of records based on a given set of records

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

Looking for help writing publish/subscribe code for publishing a set of records representing the email addresses of Meteor.users. This is tricky for me because, the publish method needs to create and return a new set based on another set...

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but if you need user emails on the client, why not just publish the subset of the users you need and filter out everything but the `emails` field?

Comment: I want a flat list of emails on the client, to be used with another component expecting such a flat list. The way I see it - this is a classic example of a need for an iterator in a publish method, that generates a new set. Or I don't have a good enough understanding of meteor's mentality...?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this with publications/subscriptions. I suggest making a [Meteor Method](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header). You can call it from the client, and on the server (because the server has permission to access everything) it will gather all the emails, and send it back to the client. Then you don't have to give the client access to any of the rest of that.

```
// On the server
Meteor.methods({
    userEmails: function() {
        users = [];

        // For each user, add the user's address to the array
        Meteor.users.forEach(function(user) {
            users.push(user.emails[0].address);
        });

        // Return the array of emails
        return users;
    }
});
```

Then, you can just call that from the client:

```
// On the client
Meteor.call('userEmails', function (error, result) {
    // When the server returns the list of emails, this will run
    if (error) {
        // There was an error
    } else {
        // Do something with the result, which is the array of emails
    }
});
```